# How to multiply each key by another key in dictionaries?

Tags: python

I'm doing course in codeacademy and i'm on lession Something of Value
In my final task i have to For each key in prices, multiply the number in prices by the number in stock. Print that value into the console and then add it to total.

My code:

```
for cena in prices:
    total = prices[cena]*stock[cena]
print total
```

It's printing `0`.

I also tried this:

```
for cena in prices:
    for ilosc in stock:
        total = prices[cena]*stock[ilosc]
print total
```

It's also returning 0.

EDIT: Whole code:

```
prices = {
    "banana" : 4,
    "apple"  : 2,
    "orange" : 1.5,
    "pear"   : 3,
}
stock = {
    "banana" : 6,
    "apple"  : 0,
    "orange" : 32,
    "pear"   : 15,
}

for key in prices:
    print key
    print "price: %s" % prices[key]
    print "stock: %s" % stock[key]
total = 0
for cena in prices:
    for ilosc in stock:
        total = prices[cena]*stock[ilosc]
print total
```

Comment: So you want to multiply the values right? can you show your dictionary or at least some items?

Comment: Might not solve it, but you should iterate through the keys using `.keys()`. `for cena in prices.keys()`

Comment: Second, I'm not sure about the specific problem, but don't you want to do `total +=` or something like that. Otherwise, after the for loop, `total` will store the product of the last two values which may be 0.

Comment: @Pushkin ```for key in dictionary``` is idiomatic why do you suggest using ```dictionary.keys()```?

Comment: @wwii Nevermind, you're right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's printing `0` because the product of the "last" items in the dictionary is `0`. If you want to know the products of each item in turn then you need to print inside the loop. If you want a total then you should either add to the existing value or use `sum()` with a generator expression (genex).

Comment: I cannot print outside of loop. Maybe my explaination are wrong so here is a picture with instructions: [link](http://i.imgur.com/A886klP.jpg)

Comment: Did you see the "add it to" in the instructions?

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me

```
prices = {
    "banana" : 4,
    "apple"  : 2,
    "orange" : 1.5,
    "pear"   : 3,
}
stock = {
    "banana" : 6,
    "apple"  : 0,
    "orange" : 32,
    "pear"   : 15,
}

for key in prices:
    print key
    print "price: %s" % prices[key]
    print "stock: %s" % stock[key]

total = 0

for key in prices:
    price_of_stock =  prices[key] * stock[key]
    print price_of_stock
    total = total + price_of_stock

print total
```

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
from itertools import chain

results = dict()
for k, v in chain(prices.iteritems(), stock.iteritems()):
  if k in results:
    results[k] *= v
  else results[k] = v
```

Answer (score 0):

I am also doing this course.My ansewer as below:

```
total=0
sums=0
for key in price:
    print key
    print "price: %s" % price[key]
    print "stock: %s" % stock[key]
for x in stock:
    sums=stock[x]*price[x] 
    print sums
    total+=sums

print total
```

Mybe can give you a ref.

Comment: That is fairly close, but not strictly correct according to the question, though it works for the sample data. You need to move the summing to the total into the loop over the price keys (and remove the second loop).